# distribute userspace and kernel component in one RPM

Tags: linux, rpm

I am writing an application on Linux that has both userspace and kernel component ( in the form of loadable module i.e. .ko). I'd like to provide this as 1 package to the user rather than having to issue 2 commands - one for userspace package installation and the other for kernel module installation.

Is it possible to distribute just 1 RPM which will include both userspace and kernel portion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

yes, RPM doesn't care about what's in a package.

However, it's against RHEL/fedora/Alma/Rocky Linux packaging *guidelines*. Whether you care is a different story.

> I'd like to provide this as 1 package to the user

Bad choice – the user must have the exact same kernel version. So, they will always want the SRPM to be able to rebuild your package when their kernel changes. And suddenly you're forcing them to rebuild things that they don't need to rebuild, because the userspace component doesn't change.

> one for userspace package installation and the other for kernel module installation.

That's an inelegant  solution for your user. Instead, use COPR to host your packages, for the multiple versions of the kernel the user might have. Then, installation is just `dnf install yourpackage`, where `yourpackage` depends on two other packages, `yourpackage-kernel-module` and `yourpackage-userspace`. And: your user gets an update channel (they can of course still manually download the packages, but it's very rare users actually *want* that).

Comment: Can’t RPMs (not SRPMs) provide `dkms`-based setups? That still leaves all the MOK side to deal with but COPR can’t handle that either. Given the cadence of Fedora kernel package releases I’m not sure it’s workable to provide pre-built modules for all kernels...

Comment: @StephenKitt yep, the do, that's true. You can have a webhook that triggers a package update on COPR every time Fedora updates the kernel headers, as well! (but you'd need to script that yourself)